# Jquery Ajax Loading another page containing jquery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jquery to load another php file, however that php file also has the jquery libraries linked to it(google's CDN). I believe this causing a conflict because on windows jquery stops working, and on mac google's webfont doesn't load and jquery doesn't load. I fixed the issue by simply removing jquery from the those pages. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading an entire other page (with its own libraries and linked resources) it might be better to load it in an iframe instead of trying to load it using jQuery/ajax and rendering it inline.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jquery AJAX than you could just look for the tags in the received context which are linked to load another Jquery and just remove them.

For the record in my oppinion you should make modules of your project so that the js part is in one place and the php part is in the other, separated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= COMMONSITE_HTTP_PATH ?>/scripts/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

If you could test for jQuery library in your second web document, it wont be injected twice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `jQuery.noConflict` is your friend.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: but wouldn't that let you without the $ function ( aka the shorthand for Jquery) ?

Comment: Huh, I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: JQuery.noConflict was designed to eliminate the window.$ function so that prototype.js or other libraries could use it. But loading twice the same JQuery one with no conflict set on and the other with off is just idiotic i think.